# youtube browser based uploader yt:authentication Unknown

Tags: youtube-api, uploading

I had used my php AP for uploading youtube videos for 2 days,
All worked just fine. 
But yesterday and today, I get this error when trying to upload videos to my youtube account.
yt:authentication Unknown

I am using OAuth2, all clientid , key, secret are correct

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever running into OAuth 2 weirdness, the first step I'd recommend is invalidating your existing grant from https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens, and then going through the OAuth 2 approval flow again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the PHP client library for the Google API and was having this same problem. In the v3 documentation, I couldn't find anything relating to a browser-based YouTube upload so I've ended up using the v3 API for some things (video and playlist retrieval, authentication etc.) but I'm still using the [v2 method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading) for browser-based uploading. All of this was working fine then suddenly stopped working. Jeff's suggestion of revoking the token does indeed work but the problem would just come back later.

What I had to do was check if the user's token had expired. Note that the YouTube token currently seems to expire after 60 minutes. If the token has expired, you need to make sure the user goes through the authentication process again. A quick example:

```
// $client is your previously authenticated instance of Google_Client
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
{
    // Redirect to your page which outputs $client->createAuthUrl() for them to authenticate again
}
```

It's probably worthwhile noting that $client->getAccessToken() still evaluates to true in conditionals even with an expired token.